# How to handle Post-Redirect-Get in NancyFx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nancy

Using the PRG pattern I often need to pass data across the redirect. Successful saving of data is the most common.

In ASP.NET MVC the TempData object can hold data that lives across exactly one redirect/request.

How should I handle this scenario in NancyFx?

Comment: :( I wish people would stop using the PGR pattern, stop sending invalid requests to the server and you don't need the PGR pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a suggestion I ended up using `session` as a fake temp data. I created a gist.
https://gist.github.com/detroitpro/4b2f7585d25ab37f2e59

```
 protected override void ApplicationStartup(IWindsorContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
        {
            pipelines.BeforeRequest += (ctx) =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.Session["TempMessage"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx.Request.Session["TempMessage"] as string))
                {
                    ctx.ViewBag.TempMessage = ctx.Request.Session["TempMessage"];
                    ctx.ViewBag.TempType = ctx.Request.Session["TempType"];
                    ctx.Request.Session.DeleteAll();
                }
                return null;
            };
        }
```